# How can a child view be notified when one of its parents isEnabled state changes?

Tags: android, android-view, isenabled

I'm trying to build up complex layouts by composting several smaller layouts and views.  For instance, we have a custom, vector-render-based icon which we display alongside a TextView and a few other accouterments in a class we call DecoratedIconTextView.

The problem is in the rendering.  The icon knows how to render itself in the normal and disabled states.  However, even if its parent DecoratedIconTextView is disabled, the icon is still reporting it itself is enabled.

Thoughts include some way to interrogate up the parent chain to see if any of them report as disabled (ala pull), and if so, treat yourself as if you were disabled.  However, that approach doesn't allow for changes to the isEnabled property of a parent to propagate down to all the children (ala push).

I'm also not sure of how to even monitor the changes to the isEnabled property as I don't see any overrides.

So how can a child be notified when its parent's isEnabled state changes?

Comment: Part of the solution will be to turn on the `android:duplicateParentState` property for all the views between the parent and your custom view. However, I'm not sure what the optimal way to implement the custom view is.

Comment: Hey... can you put this as an answer so I can mark it as such?  I think this is what I was looking for.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

When a view is enabled or disabled, the view is invalidated. Hence the onDraw() method would be called. You can extend any view and override onDraw() method and can notify your system if the views state changes.

Comment: But that would require subclassing every control in the hierarchy!  For instance, if I have my children in a LinearLayout and that LinearLayout is set to disabled, I want my children to be able to draw in a disabled state.  Subclassing LinearLayout shouldn't be needed.  Isn't there some state notification that you can listen to so you don't have to create subclasses of all the ViewGroup classes?